# How to get employee custom fields from Paylocity API?

Tags: paylocity

I'm able to get a list of all employees from the Paylocity API using this endpoint:

https://prod.cdn.paylocity.com/developer/index.html#operation/Get%20all%20employees

I'm able to then iterate over the employee list and get each one's details with this API endpoint:
https://prod.cdn.paylocity.com/developer/index.html#operation/Get%20employee

My problem is that this endpoint doesn't seem to retrieve custom fields.

There seems to be an endpoint for retrieving custom fields here:
https://prod.cdn.paylocity.com/developer/index.html#operation/Get%20All%20Custom%20Fields%20by%20category

But it's unclear to me what the value of the "category" field should be.  This endpoint seems like it may just come back with the custom field definitions, but not necessarily the values.